# Git says xcode storyboard file is modified

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, swift

Sometimes I my storyboard file in xcode shows up as modified by git even when I haven't touched it. What is causing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes when you open storyboard file it changes some numbers in it. Thats why the change

But your storyboard contents will remain the same.

This is mess when you work with multiple members and share storyboard.

I would also recommend to use [gitIgnore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore) if you are working in teams

Answer (score 2):

Xcode modifies the storyboard to match its version. If you check in the file and another developer just opens the file on a different version of Xcode, then the file will change again. So if you are all on the same version of Xcode and your storyboards have all been opened and then checked in, you should no longer see this issue when opening storyboards, until the next Xcode release. This problem happens frequently when developers are not on the same version.